# How to call Zustand / React hook outside of React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, zustand

I have this Zustand store to store authenticaction information about logged in user.

```
const authStore = (set: any) => ({
    ...initialState,
    doLogin: async (user: TLoggedInRequest) => {
        try {
            set(() => ({status: "pending"}))
            const result = await loginService.login(user)
            set(() => ({
                status: "resolved",
                user: result?.data.user,
                error: null
            }))
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("rejected error", error)
            set((state: any) => ({status: "rejected", error}))
        }
    },
    doLogout: async () => {
        await loginService.logout()
        set(() => initialState)
        history.push("/")
    }
});
```

This is `HTTPApiClient` that for communication with REST API uses Axios, example of GET method (the rest omitted for brevity).

```
async get<TResponse>(path: string): Promise<TResponse> {
    try {
        const response = await this.instance.get<TResponse>(path);
        return response.data;
    } catch (error: any) {
        handleServiceError(error);
    }
    return {} as TResponse;
}
```

And this piece of code is executed in React component when user is logging out.

```
const doLogoutSelector = (state: any) => state.doLogout;
const doLogout = useAuthStore(doLogoutSelector);

const signout = () => {
        doLogout()
        return <Navigate replace to="/"/>
}
```

I would like to logout user when `HTTPApiClient` gets `401 Unathorized` status code from the backend. I am able to recognize the 401 code in client but I don't know how to call logout hook.

**Q: How to call React the hook outside of React component?**

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The answer is simple:

```
useAuthStore.getState().doLogout()
```

E.g. my error-interceptor looks like:

```
...
if (error instanceof AxiosError && response?.status === 401) {
  useAuth.getState().logout()
}
...
```

useAuth.ts

```
export const useAuth = create((set, get) => ({
  logout: async () => {
    ...
  },
  ...
}))
```